# Ubuntu Touch photo transver via Bluetooth

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, camera

How to send photos taken with the camera of Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Touch via Bluetooth to Android tablet.The photo gallert app only allows sharing with social media (facebook, twitter), or send per email or MMS.

Comment: Related to [Ubuntu Touch Nexus 4 Bluetooth doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685125/ubuntu-touch-nexus-4-bluetooth-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

Right now transfer via bluetooth is still not included in Ubuntu Touch. Developers are currently working on it and most probably this feature will be activated with the OTA-10 update which should arrive in March, 2016. See this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1511525) report for details.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue as we are past March and yesterday, I could not transfer a photo from my Ubuntu tablet to my Ubuntu phone. There is not even the option to share via Bluetooth when you select the share option.

Comment: Sadly no. Now the bug has been put in backlog.

Comment: Oh my gosh, backlog? This is basic functionality that all the users Ubuntu Touch wish to take from the other two main players will be expecting. They will already have this working a treat and expect a better service from their new system, not a worse one. I personally think this is a big mistake to put it in the backlog. Thanks for the update though.

Comment: @phil-uk If you're on for experimenting, then you might want to try this: https://open.uappexplorer.com/app/ubtd.mzanetti

Comment: Thanks pomsky, I will install it and give it a go. Do you need me to give you comments and feedback on how it all goes?

Comment: I tries to download and install this app anf it did not allow me to. I logged in and clicked on both download and install and nothing happens. I can view the source though. Can you advise if I am doing something wrong please.

Comment: @phil-uk You'll have to download the click package first (from the download button in the link) and transfer to your phone. Then open the terminal app and change directory to the downloaded click package location (e.g. if it's the Downloads folder, then enter `cd ~/Downloads/`. Then run `ls` command, downloaded click package should be listed. Then finally enter `pkcon install-local --allow-untrusted the-downloaded-package-name.click`