# Ubuntu Touch Nexus 4 Bluetooth doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, nexus-4

I'm running latest stable version of Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4, but Bluetooth doesn't work right.

The Nexus 4 can see other devices and the Nexus 4 can be seen by other devices. But if I try to send files from my Desktop (Ubuntu 14.04) to it says "Transfer Failed (0x43)".

Can anybody help me?

Edit: I'm using the channel ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth transfer is still not included in Ubuntu Touch. Developers are currently working on it and most probably this feature will be ready with the OTA-10 update which should arrive in March, 2016. See this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1511525) report for details.

Answer (score 0):

I am an Ubuntu user with no Ubuntu Touch experience, but in Ubuntu you have to go into 'Personal File Sharing' to enable receive files over bluetooth before it will accept incoming transfers, it is part of package gnome-file-sharing' if I remember correctly.  A search of the Software Center for Personal File Sharing might lead in the right direction if you don't have it

Comment: Thanks for reply: Well, I already searched for it on my Phone, and found no further possibilities to enable file transfers. It seems to be an problem on Ubuntu Touch with my nexus 4, my I'm going to post it as a bug...